# Searching through files in Lua

Tags: file, sorting, search, lua

I am trying to have lua read through an entire file and search for all occurrences of `define_verb"<whatever>"` and the lines inbetween until it reaches an `end_verb`.

I want it to search inbetween the lines to see if it has certain key-words in it like #DEMIGOD or #GOD or #OMNIPOTENT, and if it does have those inbetween, it'll put the  after define_verb and stick it on a new line in another file called "godcommands".

Just an example here:

```
define_verb"rew)ard"

define_label"inrewardverb"

if player_flag[ply #DEMIGOD 0] then gosub"dontknow":out_verb

playnum=ply:tempivis=1233:gosub"makename":$caster=$temp

...

end_verb
```

Any help with a project like this would be sooo helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with

```
local f=assert(io.open(filename))
local T=f:read"*a"
for b in T:gmatch('define_verb.-end_verb') do
  if b:match("#DEMIGOD") or b:match("#GOD") or b:match("#OMNIPOTENT") then
    -- do something
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes that is quite useful, and very simple! Thank you. So if I did that and wanted to add the name of the verb to a new file, would I do something like this? local name = b:gmatch('define_verb"(%w+)"')